# Doing calculation in Yii is only taking manually inserted values

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-events

I am writing a small invoice application in `Yii`. I have the `database` for the model `item`. The `item database` is something like this

```
  +++++++++++++++++
  |  InvoiceItems |
  +++++++++++++++++
  +      id       +
  +      name     +
  +  description  +
  +    unit_cost  +
  +    quantity   +
  +    tax        +
  +    total      +
  +++++++++++++++++
```

Now, in `item model` I have made a dropdown list where I am fetching all the item name with its `unit_cost, quantity, tax` etc in Ajax. In order to do the `total`, I have the business logic as:

1. `unit_cost` will be multiplied by `quantity`
2. Tax will then be added to the total.
3. The total should finally pop up in the `total` field in the `_form.php` file.

For the calculation, I have written this `jQuery` script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#InvoiceItems_unit_cost, #InvoiceItems_quantity, #InvoiceItems_tax").on('keyup',function(event){
    var subtotal = jQuery("#InvoiceItems_quantity").val() * jQuery("#InvoiceItems_unit_cost").val();
    var total = subtotal + (subtotal  * jQuery("#InvoiceItems_tax").val() / 100);
    jQuery("#InvoiceItems_total").val(total);
  });
});
</script>
```

This is working fine when I am *manually inserting the values* but it's not working when the values are coming from the database. I am totally stuck.

**UPDATE**

When I am trying to see the value after fetching from the database through ajax in console tab of firefox just like `console.log("#InvoiceItems_quantity").val()`, it is showing `an empty string`.
Ajax code to fetch data from the database in form of json

```
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($customers,'customer_name',CMap::mergeArray(CHtml::listData(Customers::model()->findAll(), 'customer_name',       'customer_name'
        ),
        array(
        'empty'=>array('Select'=>'- - Choose One - -'),
        'id'=>'Customers_name',
        'ajax'=> array(
            'type'=>'GET',
            'id'=>'abc',
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('Invoices/customerdetails'),// action that will generate the data
            'data'=>'js:"customer_name="+$(this).val()',// this is the data that we are sending to the action in the controller
            'dataType'=>'json',// type of data we expect back from the server
            'success'=>'js:updateFieldsCustomers',// a javascript function that will execute when the request completes
            'beforeSend'=>'js:function(){
                if($("#Customers_name").val() == "create_customer_link") {
                    addCustomers();
                    $("#dialogCustomers").dialog("open");
                    return false;
                }
            }',
        ),
        'options'=>array(
            'create_customer_link' => array('class'=>'create-link'),
        )
    )
);?>

   <?php
  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('update','
  function updateFieldsCustomers(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  // select each input field by id, and update its value
  $("#InvoiceItems_unit_cost").val(data.unit_cost);
  $("#InvoiceItems_quantity").val(data.quantity);
  $("#InvoiceItems_discount").val(data.discount);
  // similarly update the fields for the other inputs
  }
');
  ?>
```

**Recent Update**

When I tried for `console.log("#InvoiceItems_quantity").val()` I saw that it is showing the actual value of that field after change. Means when one value is selected it is showing the value of previous entered value in console panel. I think all this is working as I have used `on change` function but when I am using `.select` its not working at all.Not any value is showing in console panel.

Comment: `console.log("#Items_quantity")` ? It must be `console.log(jQuery("#Items_quantity").val())`. And pls edit the question with the ajax code you are using to update the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this question. It should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#Product_name").ajaxComplete(function(event,request,settings){
    var subtotal = jQuery("#InvoiceItems_quantity").val() * jQuery("#InvoiceItems_unit_cost").val();
    var total = subtotal + (subtotal  * jQuery("#InvoiceItems_tax").val() / 100);
    jQuery("#InvoiceItems_total").val(total);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#Items_unit_cost, #Items_quantity, #Items_discount").on('keyup',calculate_total);

     function calculate_total(){
           var subtotal = jQuery("#Items_quantity").val() * jQuery("#Items_unit_cost").val();
           var total = subtotal + (subtotal  * jQuery("#Items_discount").val() / 100);
           jQuery("#Items_total").val(total);
         }

calculate_total();

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Nope..this is not working. Here also user have to insert values manually to get the total. I want the values fetched from the database should do the calculation and show the total.

Comment: had you set the values in textboxes  after they fetched from database ?

Comment: NewUser: look like you are using a dropdown to fetch the data(ajax) and populate the textboxes. So,a fter setting the values in textboxes... just call calculate_total()  .... or   ..... handle 'change' event on dropdown box something like ...  JQuery('#Your_Dropdown_box_ID_here').on('change', calculate_total).

Comment: Nope..The `jQuery('#dropdown_box_ID').on('change',function(event){
})` not working here.

Comment: not working isn't a error message. Did you look at JS console?

Comment: @Gopesh yes I have checked that.

Comment: @SuVeRa.I used `.on('change',function(event){})`.It is working fine but the problem is it is working after changing the value. I want when the value is selected it should show the calculation of that particular id, but it is showing the calculation of that id when it is already changed.

Comment: @NewUser This answer looks fine. You just need to place a call to `calculate_total()` at the end of  the `updateFieldsCustomer()` function.